# Mimic UITableViewCellStyleValue1 accessoryType-detailTextLabel spacing with Autolayout?

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

When using a default UITableViewCell with UITableViewCellStyleValue1 the detailTextLabel is aware of the accessoryType. The distance between the label and the edge of the cell is different from the distance between the label and the accessoryType view. When I use a custom UITableViewCell subclass the two distances are equal. Which doesn't look as nice as the default implementation.

It's a bit hard to explain, so here is a screenshot:

[image]

The first two cells are default UITableViewCell with UITableViewCellStyleValue1.
Cell 3 and 4 are custom cells that were setup with a `H:[label]-16-|` constraint.
Cell 5 and 6 are custom cells that were setup with a `Trailing-0-TrailingMargin` constraint.

I want to get the behavior of the default cell for my own cells. How can I achieve that with autolayout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS actually moves the `contentView` around, so the solution is to simply adjust the distance between the contentView and the label:

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    /* ... */
    trailingDetailConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: rightLabel, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1, constant: 15)
    contentView.addConstraint(trailingDetailConstraint)
}

override var accessoryType: UITableViewCellAccessoryType {
    didSet {
        if accessoryType == .None {
            trailingDetailConstraint.constant = 15
        }
        else {
            trailingDetailConstraint.constant = 0
        }
        layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}

override var editingAccessoryType: UITableViewCellAccessoryType {
    didSet {
        if accessoryType == .None {
            trailingDetailConstraint.constant = 15
        }
        else {
            trailingDetailConstraint.constant = 0
        }
        layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great. Do you have the same example in Objective-C?